# Unable to connect to local Postgres via GUI

Tags: postgresql, postico, table-plus

I recently ran a Postgres via Docker where in I have a `Dockerfile` that copies an *init script* to add new user, enable UUID extension, created database and grant privileges.

I can login using the default user "postgres" but not the second account "XXX_itsm". It says **FATAL: database "XXX_itsm" does not exist.**
What I'm planning to do is just create a database but another problem occurred when connecting via GUI (Postico / TablePlus).

[image]

Which leads me to the following questions:

1. What is the proper way of creating a user? (I have this current init script in entrypoint)
   [image]
   *NOTE: I have the variables defined in Dockerfile ENV DB_USER DB_PASS DB_NAME*
2. Why it's only allowing me to login in GUI with the default user?

Comment: For the password problem, what does the servers log file give for the error?

Comment: It says `DETAIL: Password does not match for user "XXX_itsm". Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"`. At the moment, I'm not sure why but `psql` command to login is ok.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you type in the same password for both programs?  Are there any weird characters that Postico might not like in it?

Comment: Yes @jjames, I am sure I've typed the exact working password in Postico. This is really weird. I already recreated the images, volume, container multiple times.

Comment: At the moment tried to use alphanumeric password and it's working. Previously I have special characters `_ ! $ @`. After further checking, the `@` is causing the issue when logging in via GUI so I had to removed it and now it works. Maybe this is a bug with Postico / TablePlus (I don't know).

Comment: Yeah, that does sound like a bug.